# AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader), on shared Tomcat Environment

Tags: spring, security, tomcat

I have taken up a project that must be implemented in a shared tomcat 3rd party environment. My app uses Spring 3.1.2 and Hibernate 4. When the 3rd party admins load the app I get the error message about not having the permission to create a class loader. You can have a look hereunder

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader) 

Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader) 
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
```

I know that many articles online suggest that someone should enable that permission in order for spring to work, but this can not be accepted by the 3rd party. Does anyone have a knowledge if this could be worked around with a change in configuration?

in this article I see that this permission is needed for aspectJ features. Maybe if I could disable them?
http://www.sevagas.com/?Spring-and-Hibernate-Tomcat

Any configuration file is available if needed :)
Thanks for your time!

Comment: No one has ever faced something similar? with all these shared tomcat environments? The answer of the 3rd party host is precise on what I was afraid. They insist on me changing my code in order not to have the erorrs . Please could you advise?

thanks!!